# SF Duplicate Management: Only want to search for duplicates across one record type

Tags: record-type, duplicate-management

I'm toying around with the new duplicate management functionality and am coming across something that seems counter-intuitive. We have two record types for contact and I set up a duplicate rule so that it only runs when we're creating/editing contacts for "Record Type 1". Here's the issue:

Although the duplicate rules don't run when creating/editing a contact from "Record Type 2", I can't stop the system from looking at "Record Type 2" contacts when creating "Record Type 1" contacts. If someone is creating a contact of "Record Type 1", it also searches for duplicates from within "Record Type 2".

Does that make sense? Does anyone know a way to make it so we only search for duplicates across one record type?